# Container shape not available

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I'm looking to use Draw.io to create some process maps. I can see from tutorials / other posts on this forum that I should use the *Container* shape, under *General Shapes*, in order to get a swimlane.

However, that shape does not appear to be available to me.
Is there something additional I need to do / install to get that shape?

Answer (score 1):

Look into the `advanced` library.